# Previous column matching and mutate a new col in R

Tags: r

I have the following data :

```
Cust <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3)
Date <- c("2017-07-10","2017-07-10","2017-07-10","2017-07-10","2017-07-11","2017-07-15","2017-07-15","2017-07-15","2017-06-19","2017-07-19")
TCode <- c(123,123,125,125,124,231,231,234,236,332)
H <- c("A","B","C","D","E","FF",'G',"H","J","GG")
df <- data.frame(Cust,Date,TCode,H)
```

Now, I have to make a new column "Newcol(df$NewCol)' in such a way that if `Cust[1] == Cust[2]` and `TCode[1]==TCode[2]`, then the value in `df$new_col[2]=df$new_col[1]` will be same as the previous one, else add 1 to it.
This will change when the Cust Number change and again start with 1.

NOTE : For every new value in `df$Cust`, the first occurrence in `df$new_col` will always be 1
The total number of rows is greater than 1M, so need it to be dynamic.

The output needed is as follows :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
df$New_col <- with(df, ave(TCode, Cust, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x))))
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, New_col := rleid(TCode), by = Cust]
```

Using `dplyr` with `rleid` from `data.table`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Cust) %>% 
  mutate(New_col = rleid(TCode))
```

Gives us:

```
  Cust       Date TCode  H New_col
 1:    1 2017-07-10   123  A       1
 2:    1 2017-07-10   123  B       1
 3:    1 2017-07-10   125  C       2
 4:    1 2017-07-10   125  D       2
 5:    1 2017-07-11   124  E       3
 6:    2 2017-07-15   231 FF       1
 7:    2 2017-07-15   231  G       1
 8:    2 2017-07-15   234  H       2
 9:    2 2017-06-19   236  J       3
10:    3 2017-07-19   332 GG       1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with dplyr library. I have a spark data frame , not sure where rleid() function of data.table will work or not!